# Is loan / finance job is halaal for muslim?

Tags: work, finance

Assalam u alaikum
My husband is working as an  ASM in a financial company from last 15 years. As l had gone through quraan translation i came to know that direct/ indirect riba, people who make entry of riba & guaranter all are equally involved in sin.He is now in search of another job but after so many years of this profession he is not getting any job suitable fir him.
Kindly suggest the shariah solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

Yes... It is a sin to take or give a loan. He should continuously try to find another job and hope so he will get it.

Comment: It is a sin to take riba on a loan, a loan may be given without riba.